# When moving something by entrainment in a fluid stream, where does the energy come from?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation, buoyancy

The particular Something I had in mind here would be air bubbles that are pulled downwards against their buoyancy by a stream of water falling down a shaft. The work required to push those bubbles down must decrease energy somewhere else, so where does it come from? Is the stream's velocity reduced?

Comment: What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

Entrainment works by the entraining medium giving momentum and energy to the entrained medium. [The Wiki page on the injector pump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injector) should get you started.